# Elan touchpad sensitivity per application in Windows 10 on Lenovo Flex 2-14

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Flex with Windows 10 Home, and since upgrading to Windows 10, the Elan mousepad has been acting a bit unexpectedly. In certain applications, the scroll sensitivity is similar to what I am used to from Windows 8, but in others, the mousepad has become hypersensitive. I.e., in some applications, the slightest scrolling (two-finger motion on the mousepad)

**Applications that I can no longer use due to hypersensitive scrolling:**

- Sublime Text 3
- Spotify desktop client
- Command Line
- Elan TrackPad settings (ironically)

**Applications that seem to be working as before:**

- Google Chrome
- Windows Explorer

Even at the lowest sensitivity setting, when e.g. chrome becomes unbearably slow, Sublime Text is impossible to navigate because any scroll motion jumps to the bottom or the top. 
I have downloaded the latest driver for my computer from Lenovo's support portal (11.4.63.4_x64_whql), but the problem persists. Does anyone know a solution to this problem, alternatively a way to adjust app-specific sensitivity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone else struggles with similar issues, I found a fix that I haven't seen described anywhere else on the web:

In the registry editor (just press the Windows button and search for "`regedit`"), I found a key called "`ScrollControl_Mode`".

**For me, this was under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Elantech\SmartPad`**, but I have also seen references to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP` for Synaptics mousepads.

When setting the `ScrollControl_Mode` to 1 rather than 0, scroll started behaving with reasonable speed in Spotify, Sublime Text, etc.

Comment: I had the issue in PowerShell and I've changed the ScrollControl_Mode value with the following command: Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Elantech\SmartPad -name ScrollControl_Mode -Value 1 . Now my touchpad works ok in the console. Thank you so much for pointing out that obscure key!